# Message passing and model trains control system and user interface programming

Tags: network-programming

I am designing a control system and user interface for a model train infrastructure and I was wondering if this is the technology to use? I mean Message Passing if yes which programming language is best to use for this purpose? Has anyone got any pointers on where to start? I know some java and c#!

Many thanks

Comment: "message passing" isn't a technology, or even a technique, it's just a vague design pattern.

Comment: this still leaves me in a more confusing situation??

Answer (score 0):

If you can put in some effort and learn WPF for interface designing, then that would be cool. Otherwise you can use windows forms in C#.NET.
You can use remoting for communication but if you are concerned with performance then you can use sockets and Google's protobuf for message contraction and serialization/deserialization. You can find a port of protobuf for .NET at http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/. Its super easy and fast.
Thats the most I can suggest from the the amount of information you have put in the question.

Comment: thanks for this...i will investigate what can be done using this.

Good forum!